# Javascript library to convert regex matches to button

Tags: javascript, regex, input, widget

I saw several autocomplete (tag) libraries, but can't find anything that convert regex results to buttons. Just like a email to email-button system in an input.

All I find is tagging widgets in js. Is this something that exists?

What I'm searching is that:

[image]

Which isn't a tagging functionality, just a regex-matches-to-buttons functionality.

So, all I would have to do is to specify a div, a regex and a class, and it would handle the rest.

Edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/leye0/nLnBk/6/ That's both an email-to-button and autocomplete `Code` I've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would create something with the text that was in the match:

```
var regexMatch = "Test Regex Here".match(/[\w\d ]*/i);
var btn = document.createElement("button");
var t = document.createTextNode(regexMatch);

if(regexMatch)
{
  btn.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Then use [JQuery's](http://jquery.com/) [token input plug-in](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) to achieve the results you're looking for.

Comment: I finally created something that handles both autocomplete list and email detection. http://jsfiddle.net/DDGJu/5/ but could say this answer inspired me.